# pow function in C

Tags: c, gcc, pow, math.h

I write a C code that have power function that is from math.h library. when I compiled my program, I received an error which is " undefined reference to 'pow' function ", I compile my program using gcc compiler (fedora 9).

I insert -lm flag to gcc then, the error is omitted but the output of the pow function is 0.

```
#include<math.h>
main()
{
double a = 4, b = 2;
b = pow(b,a);
}
```

Can anyone help me? Is there is a problem in my compiler??

Thanks.

Comment: *the error is omitted but the output is 0* What output ? You're not printing anything.

Comment: @cnicutar - maybe OP meant the _return value_ of `pow()`?

Comment: I use printf("%d\n", b); to print the value.

Comment: And it was the printf line that contained the error. Make sure you post ALL of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C's pow() doesn't work with a variable exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802263/cs-pow-doesnt-work-with-a-variable-exponent)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your program doesn't output anything.

The 0 you are referring to is probably the exit code, which will be 0 if you don't explicitly return from `main`.

Try changing it to a standards-compliant signature and return `b`:

```
int main(void) {
  ...
  return b;
}
```

Note that the return values is essentially limited to 8 bits-worth of information, so very, very limited.

Use `printf` to display the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
  printf("%f\n", b);
...
```

You **must** use a floating point conversion specifier (`f`, `g` or `e`) to print `double` values. You cannot use `d` or others and expect consistent output. (This would in fact be undefined behavior.)

Comment: Good answer. My guess is the OP is using the wrong printf specifier.

Comment: I use printf to display the b value. the value of b is 0. I use %d specifier.

Comment: If you use printf like I put it above, you'll see `16.0000...`. `%d` is for integer types.

Comment: @cnicutar: your crystal ball is very strong.

Answer (score 15):

For everyone else who seek such an answer:

**This will not work**:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program
```

It will produce something like this:

```
/tmp/cc8li91s.o: In function `main':
my_program.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**This will work**:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program -lm
```

Comment: This is already stated in the question itself. (And in numerous other Qs and As on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 4):

You are lacking the printf line to print the value to stdout.
Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
        double a=4, b=2, c;

        c = pow(b,a);
        printf("%g^%g=%g\n", a,b,c);
        return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
4^2=16
```

Answer (score 4):

There is confusion here regarding base and exponent. This is not immediately apparent because both 2^4 and 4^2 equal 16.

```
void powQuestion()
{
    double a, b, c;

    a = 4.0;
    b = 2.0;
    c = pow(b, a);

    printf("%g ^ %g = %g\n", a,b,c);        // Output: 4 ^ 2 = 16

    a = 9.0;
    b = 2.0;
    c = pow(b, a);

    printf("%g ^ %g = %g\n", a,b,c);        // Output: 9 ^ 2 = 512  >> Wrong result; 512 should be 81 <<


    // K & R, Second Edition, Fifty Second Printing, p 251: pow(x,y) x to the y

    double x, y, p;

    x = 9.0;
    y = 2.0;
    p = pow(x, y);

    printf("%g ^ %g = %g\n", x, y, p);      // Output: 9 ^ 2 = 81


    // even more explicitly

    double base, exponent, power;

    base = 9.0;
    exponent = 2.0;
    power = pow(base, exponent);

    printf("%g ^ %g = %g\n", base, exponent, power);    // Output: 9 ^ 2 = 81
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pow() function return value of double data type

so, we have to declare variable of data type double or float where we store pow() value

### error in your code

```
use printf to print value





#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
        int a=4, b=2;
        double result;

        result = pow(b,a);
        printf("%d^%d=%g\n", a,b,result);
        return 0;
 }
```

Comment: There is no error in op's code, it just doesn't do anything. `b = pow(a,b)` correctly calculates `a` to the power of `b` and stores it in `b`, and `b` is a `double` so it's fine. The only thing missing in op's code is a `printf` to create some sort of output